# Limit Azure API usage to my domain

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I use some of Azure's Cognitive Services via JavaScript on my website. How can I avoid that anybody grabs the key and uses up my quotas? Other API providers I've worked with allow the user to limit the key to certain domains but I just can't find such a setting in the Azure backend.

Comment: I couldn't find anything either... I suppose you might need to consider having your JS call a 'relay server' that you own, where the server itself contains the cognitive key and not the client.

Comment: As @Porschiey said if you want to use a relay server a nice fit in Azure is its APIM PAAS service (API Gateway) where you can configure rate limits and domain restrictions and configure the key and invoke cognitive services.

Comment: In the meantime I contacted Microsoft's support. They say limiting the keys to domains (as Google or Twitter do) doesn't make sense because you can fake the `HOST` header. At least that would make stealing a bit more difficult, though.
As far as I can see there is no way to protect the keys in the frontend, so there's no way around a server-side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid that anybody grabs the key and uses up my quotas?

*Open door*: Don't put your key in a plain text readable file.
Whatever JavaScript trickery you want to use, the code is available. So the key is out there.

*Obvious answer*: Keep the key server-side and solve it this way. Yes, it's an extra trip. But you can beef up the filtering of requests a lot more. Like you said, you could fake a *host*. So use this to make sure nobody is using up your quota.

*"[I still want it clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22465282/7152407)"* then Steven Legett has some ideas for you.
**USE HTTPS!**